# How to get ipu6 webcam (XPS 14 9440) to work on Meteor Lake platform?

Tags: drivers, webcam

I try to get the webcam on a XPS 14 9440 on Ubuntu 23.10 to work. Since the notebook is Meteor Lake based, I've to use a current kernel (>= 6.7) to get proper Meteor Lake support. I use 6.8 mainline kernel.

```
$ uname -a
Linux christoph-XPS-14-9440 6.8.1-060801-generic #202403151937 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 15 19:52:22 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Unfortunately there are no prebuild IPU6 drivers available for kernels >= 6.7, because there are at this point in time (29. March 2024) open PRs (https://github.com/intel/ivsc-driver/pull/44, https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers/pull/213) that are required to make them work on current kernels.

How can i get the drivers properly working?
It's totally confusing for me what all the things do and how they work together to get the webcam working. I mainly just followed the readmes without much knowledge how everything is connected. So while `ipu6` are the actual drivers, what is `icamera`, `IPU6 HAL` and how is it all connected to `Gstreamer` to get the webcam work in applications?

So I tried to compile it on my own and it worked successfully with the `ipu6-drivers` (incl. `ivsc-driver`). They are compiled and loaded successfully, as far as i can see.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep ipu6
[    2.930531] intel_ipu6: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.930538] intel_ipu6: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.952118] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.953006] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Device 0x7d19 (rev: 0x4)
[    2.953039] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: physical base address 0x5a2c000000
[    2.953043] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: mapped as: 0x00000000dd7e4357
[    2.953110] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU in secure mode
[    2.953114] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU secure touch = 0x80000000
[    2.953115] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU camera mask = 0x0
[    2.964890] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPC reset done
[    2.964895] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: cpd file name: intel/ipu6epmtl_fw.bin
[    3.029032] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: FW version: 20230925
[    3.053964] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Found supported sensor OVTI02C1:00
[    3.054199] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Connected 1 cameras
[    3.055424] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending BOOT_LOAD to CSE
[    3.090594] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: Sending AUTHENTICATE_RUN to CSE
[    3.137096] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: CSE authenticate_run done
[    3.137135] intel-ipu6 0000:00:05.0: IPU6-v4 driver version 1.0
[    4.221346] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: pkg_dir entry count:8
[    4.223677] intel-ipu6-psys intel-ipu6-psys0: psys probe minor: 0
```

```
$ lsmod | grep ipu6
intel_ipu6_isys       159744  0
videobuf2_dma_contig    24576  1 intel_ipu6_isys
videobuf2_v4l2         40960  1 intel_ipu6_isys
videobuf2_common       86016  4 videobuf2_dma_contig,videobuf2_v4l2,intel_ipu6_isys,videobuf2_memops
intel_ipu6_psys       110592  0
v4l2_fwnode            40960  2 ov02c10,intel_ipu6_isys
v4l2_async             28672  3 v4l2_fwnode,ov02c10,intel_ipu6_isys
videodev              364544  5 v4l2_async,v4l2_fwnode,videobuf2_v4l2,ov02c10,intel_ipu6_isys
intel_ipu6            122880  2 intel_ipu6_isys,intel_ipu6_psys
mc                     86016  7 v4l2_async,videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,ov02c10,intel_ipu6_isys,videobuf2_common
```

However, as far as I understand I've to additionally compile `ipu6-camera-hal` including `icamerasrc` (https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers) to get the webcam actually working in applications (Google Chrome would be most important for me).
I cloned `https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal` and placed it beside the `icamerasrc_slim_api` branch of the [icamera repo](https://github.com/intel/icamerasrc/tree/icamerasrc_slim_api) as it's mentioned in the readme.

```
#from readme https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal?tab=readme-ov-file#build-instructions

cp build.sh .. && cd ..
# work
# ├── build.sh
# ├── icamerasrc
# ├── ipu6-camera-hal
# └── out
```

```
$ ls
build.sh  icamerasrc  ipu6-camera-hal  out
```

When I now try to run `build.sh` it seems to successfully build `ipu6-camera-hal` but fails on `icamerasrc`.

```
mv -f .deps/libgsticamerasrc_la-gstcampushsrc.Tpo .deps/libgsticamerasrc_la-gstcampushsrc.Plo
utils.cpp: In function 'gboolean CameraSrcUtils::gst_video_info_from_dma_drm_caps(GstVideoInfo*, const GstCaps*)':
utils.cpp:361:8: error: 'gst_video_is_dma_drm_caps' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'gst_video_info_from_caps'?
  361 |   if (!gst_video_is_dma_drm_caps(caps)) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |        gst_video_info_from_caps
utils.cpp:366:5: error: 'GstVideoInfoDmaDrm' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'GstVideoInfo'?
  366 |     GstVideoInfoDmaDrm drm_info;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     GstVideoInfo
utils.cpp:367:44: error: 'drm_info' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'g_info'?
  367 |     if (!gst_video_info_dma_drm_from_caps(&drm_info, caps)) {
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~
      |                                            g_info
```

I had similar issues before, but for them I could find missing packages that I had to install to provide the missing libs. But in that case I can't find how to solve it.